# How to add categories to WordPress block patterns?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create categories for WP block patterns. So far I have:

```
// Custom taxonomy for wp_block post type
function register_patterns_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Pattern category',
        'singular_name' => 'Pattern category',
        'search_items' => 'Search Patterns categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Patterns categories',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Pattern category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Pattern category:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Pattern category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Pattern category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Pattern category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Pattern category Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Patterns categories',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'patterns_categories' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'patterns_categories', array( 'wp_block' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_patterns_taxonomy' );

// creating patters categories by taxonomy terms
function create_block_pattern_category_for_terms() {
    $taxonomy = 'patterns_categories'; // Zmień na nazwę swojej taksonomii
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false, // Pobierz wszystkie termy, także te puste
    ) );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $pattern_category = sanitize_title( $term->name ); // Tworzenie unikalnej nazwy kategorii
        $pattern_category_exists = get_terms( 'patterns_categories', array( 'slug' => $pattern_category ) );

        register_block_pattern_category(
            $term->slug,
            array( 'label' => __( $term->name, 'wpdocs-my-plugin' ) )
        );

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_pattern_category_for_terms' );
```

and that works fine, I have custom taxonomy visible in block pattern post, also I successfully created blocks pattern categories based on custom taxonomy terms.

But now, I need to add somehow these terms to blocks patterns.

My idea is using register_block_pattern() for each post in wp_block post type, and add properly: title, content and categories. So I've tried:

```
// trying to create patterns
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wp_block',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    $title = get_the_title();
    $content = get_the_content();

    // Fetch terms associated with this post
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'patterns_categories', array('fields' => 'slugs'));

    // Create block pattern
    register_block_pattern(
        'handy-options/' . $title,
        array(
            'title'       => $title,
            'description' => _x('Two horizontal buttons, the left button is filled in, and the right button is outlined.', 'Block pattern description', 'theme-slug'),
            'categories'  => $terms,
            'content'     => wp_json_encode($content),
        )
    );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

but I don't know is this a good way - although new block patters are created with correct title, I can't add terms and content correctly.

Any advice, idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you come to register your block pattern, it's best to add that to a hook which loads the patterns only when editing or adding a post/page etc.

The main error is the JSON-encoded content. Just add the post_content, and it'll display just fine.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'register_theme_patterns' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'register_theme_patterns' );

function register_theme_patterns()
{

    if ( !function_exists( 'register_block_pattern' ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Query all published patterns.
    $patterns = new WP_Query( [ 
        'post_type' => 'wp_block',
        'number_posts' => -1
    ] );

    if ( $patterns->have_posts() )
    {

        while ( $patterns->have_posts() )
        {
            $patterns->the_post();
            global $post;

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'patterns_categories', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

            register_block_pattern(
                sprintf( 'theme-patterns/%s', sanitize_key( $post->post_name ) ),
                [ 
                    'title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $post->post_title ),
                    'content' => $post->post_content,
                    'categories' => $terms
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```